# How do you pronounce "archmage"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, speech

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(fantasy)):

> The term archmage is used in fantasy works as a title for a powerful magician or a leader of magicians.

Should it be pronounced *arch*, *ark*, or some other way?

Comment: arch: Brit. /ɑːtʃ/, U.S./ɑrtʃ/

Comment: I agree. Follow the pronunciation of non-fictional words, like *archbishop*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked a few online dictionaries like [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/archmage), [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/archmage), [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/archmage), but none of them gives its pronunciation. I didn't find 'archmage' in other online dictionaries.

There are some guidelines for how to pronounce *arch-*:

- In words that were compounded in Greek, *arch-* is pronounced with a /k/ as in *archangel, architecture, archive* etc.
- Words in which the *arch-* is followed by a consonant, it's pronounced with /t͡ʃ/ as in *archbishop, archduke* etc.
- Compound words in which the *arch-* is added to an English word, it's usually pronounced with /t͡ʃ/ such as archenemy (from Greek *arch-* and English *enemy*).

I believe *archmage* belongs to the second category and is pronounced with /t͡ʃ/.

Comment: Except for *archangel*. But that came from the Greek *arkhangelos*, and wasn't formed in English.

Comment: @PeterShor: Exactly. So it was compounded in Greek and follows the first point.

Answer (score 1):

Where *arch-* is a prefix indicating the top of a hierarchy, it's pronounced /-tʃ/ rather than /-k/. Cf *archbishop, archdeacon* and *arch-criminal.*

Where the Greek *archi-* prefix is retained in English, it has the *k* sound: *architect, archiepiscopal, archidiaconal.*

See [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/arch-):

> **arch-**
> Chief; principal.
> Pronunciation /ɑːtʃ/

(In passing, *archmage* is a curious mixture of Greek *archi-* and Latin *magus.* Not a good thing.)

Comment: But _archangel_ seems, on the surface, to fulfil your first test.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's always at least one exception to every "rule" in English -- but that particular word has a vowel following *arch-* Perhaps I should have mentioned that in the second paragraph.

Comment: Apart from the neologism (it's in Wiktionary; I suppose that grants wordness) here, all this has been said before. By yourself, I believe.